# Como adicionar primary key em uma coluna já existente de uma tabela já populada

Tags: sql-server

Possuo uma tabela já populada, nesta tabela possuo a coluna DeviceIMEI a qual desejo transformar em primary key. Existe alguma forma de fazer isto sem ter que esvaziar a tabela ?

Estou tentando desta forma:

```
alter table TableName add constraind PK_DeviceIMEI primary key (DeviceIMEI)
```

Comment: Está apresentando algum erro? Se sim, qual erro?

Comment: não seria `add constraint` ??? está com erro ai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim tem, o comando é um [ALTER TABLE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
ALTER TABLE nome-da-tablea ADD PRIMARY KEY (nome-do-campo)
```

Agora, o conteúdo do campo deve respeitar as regras de uma *primary key* (citado do link acima):

> **Limitations and Restrictions** A table can contain only one PRIMARY KEY constraint.
>
> - All columns defined within a PRIMARY KEY constraint must be defined as NOT NULL.
> - If nullability is not specified, all columns participating in a PRIMARY KEY constraint have their nullability set to NOT NULL.

Ou seja:

- A tabela só pode ter uma chave primária
- Se não for especificado, os campos que fazer parte da primary key deve ser não-nulos

Se tiver valores duplicados na chave vai dar erro, por tanto basta validar/corrigir/excluir os dados que não respeitem as regras da *primary key* que vai funcionar

Comment: Editei a pergunta adicionando um exemplo de como estou tentando fazer a alteração. Se poder me apontar onde esta o erro agradeço.

Comment: comentei lá, se for esse comando igual ao da pergunta o `constraint` está errado, mas pode usar só `add primary key`